# Heroku: Couldn't find that app / Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, deployment

I've written an Angular-app, that I wish to deploy to Heroku, but I keep getting errors...

When trying to go to the web URL where my app is deployed to, I get the following error:

```
not found
```

When trying to push: `git heroku push master` I get:

```
Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
```

When entering heroku logs -tail, I get the following

```
! Couldn't find that app.
```

but when running heroku apps, it shows my `app-name (eu)`

When running heroku info --app app-name I get the exact web url, that I've tried.

I've also tried `heroku auth:login` but that doesn't help.

My `package-json` looks as follow:

```
{ 
   "name":"app-name",
   "version":"0.0.0",
   "engines":{ 
      "node":"10.16.3"
   },
   "scripts":{ 
      "ng":"ng",
      "start":"node server.js",
      "heroku-postbuild":"ng build --prod",
      "build":"ng build",
      "test":"ng test",
      "lint":"ng lint",
      "e2e":"ng e2e"
   },
   "private":true,
   "dependencies":{ 
      "@angular/animations":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/cdk":"~8.2.3",
      "@angular/common":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/compiler":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/cli":"1.4.9",
      "@angular/compiler-cli":"^4.4.6",
      "@angular/core":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/forms":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/material":"^8.2.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/router":"~8.2.11",
      "rxjs":"~6.4.0",
      "tslib":"^1.10.0",
      "zone.js":"~0.9.1",
      "typescript":"~2.3.3"
   },
   "devDependencies":{ 
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular":"~0.803.13",
      "@angular/cli":"~8.3.13",
      "@angular/compiler-cli":"~8.2.11",
      "@angular/language-service":"~8.2.11",
      "@types/jasmine":"~3.3.8",
      "@types/jasminewd2":"~2.0.3",
      "@types/node":"~8.9.4",
      "codelyzer":"^5.0.0",
      "enhanced-resolve":"^3.3.0",
      "jasmine-core":"~3.4.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter":"~4.2.1",
      "karma":"~4.1.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher":"~2.2.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter":"~2.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine":"~2.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter":"^1.4.0",
      "protractor":"~5.4.0",
      "ts-node":"~7.0.0",
      "tslint":"~5.15.0",
      "typescript":"~3.5.3"
   }
}
```

I've tried every SO-answer in here regarding this subject, but nothing works. I've created a `server.js` file as follows:

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/app-name'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/app-name/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Also I've tried uncommenting and removing node_modules, but also tried to insert it, still no change.

I've also double checked the node -v..

My Procfile looks as this:

```
web: npm start
```

**What am I doing wrong???**

Update (passing in file structure):

[image: file structure]

Update (updated my package-json file)

I've made some minor updates to the `package.json` file, so not it gets pushed to master, but still I get the "not found" message when visiting the url.

Also the logs -tail shows "Couldn't find that app"... Very frustrating...

Comment: can you share your files structure

Comment: @Mohammednaji I've updated my question, if that is what you've meant?

Comment: after pushing to Heroku , did the build pass?

Comment: yes, but I still get the "not found" message, when entering the URL.

Comment: so, let's back to the logs -tail problem, I believe that you miss spelling the app name,
also can you run command `bash` and check the files manually, I mean we need to check if the heroku post-build worked fine

Comment: I've checked the spellings and nothing found there. When entering "bash" it tells me that the term is not recognized. My postbuild is right now "ng build --prod"

Comment: use CLI to run this command `heroku run bash --app app-name`

Comment: I can see - when inspecting the site - that I get "Refused to load the image <app-url> because it violates the following Content Security Policies directive "default-src"..."

Comment: @Mohammednaji - U were right! Double checked and it was because of a typo inside app name. Thanks a lot for the help, I guess I was getting blind and event though I thought the spelling was right in the first place it wasn't - simple mistake costed several hours..

Comment: I will make my comment as Answer so anyway have same problem , can find it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I believe that you miss spelling the app name**